# php5-common package unmet dependency

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, apache2, php

I went to update the distribution of Ubuntu so I ran Terminal, entering `apt-get dist-update` and got this error:

```
 php5-mysql depends on php5-common (= 5.6.21+dfsg-1+donate.sury.org~precise+1); however:
 Version of php5-common on system is 5.6.21+dfsg-1+donate.sury.org~precise+2.
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Patience, young Padawan, you just need to wait a tad bit longer.  In the PPAs, architecture independent packages (`php5-common`) can be built on different architecture at different time.

Answer (score 0):

If you experience this error that means the version of both `php5-common` and `php5-mysql` was different thus causing this error, To fix the error, Do:

```
sudo apt-get install php5 php5-common php5-mysql
```

Try `sudo apt-get dist-update` again, hope it helps you.